# Spaces in String after Join VB6

Tags: join, vb6

```
Private Sub FKeyButton_Click(Index As Integer)

    Dim curChild As Form
    Set curChild = frmMain.ActiveForm

    Dim funcStr As String
    Dim funcStrA(3) As String
    funcStrA(0) = "F"
    funcStrA(1) = str(Index)
    funcStrA(2) = "_Click"

    funcStr = Join(funcStrA, "")

    If ExistsFunction(funcStr, curChild) Then
        CallByName curChild, funcStr, VbMethod
    End If

End Sub
```

The result should be, that a function in the actual mdichild is called, when a button is clicked.

for example the button with the index '7' is clicked, the String 'funcStr' should have the value "F7_Click".
But the value is "F 7_Click", and the existfunction returns false.

I think the problem is within the join, but i also tried to trim, but there is no effect.

Comment: Why not use a control array for the `curChild` buttons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, if I recall correctly, it's the `Str()` function.  It prepends a space as a placeholder for the sign.  Use `CStr()` or just assign the `Index` directly to `funcStrA(1)` and let it get implictly converted to a string.

Comment: Also i removed the whole array thing, 
    ("F" + CStr(Index) + "_Click") 
was enough.
I thougth i need to join...

Comment: Str() can have other side-effects too.  For one thing it is locale-blind and always uses "universal" (i.e. U.S. English) punctuation.  It will never use "," as a decimal point.